# How do I create a gallery within the application and show the photos and videos in the file I want?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have photos and videos in the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` folder. How can I create a gallery page and show the videos and photos in this folder?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_gallery

Comment: I know there is such a package but how can I show only the media in the folder I want?

Comment: It's written in docs, you can list all the albums (folders), then you can take one specific folder, by name for example. And for that folder, you can list all media.

Comment: What can you do so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to get from the file path I want.